# Customize BibLaTeX: Automatically generate N.N./ O.V. (no author) and n.d./ o.J. (no date) in bibliography (style alphabetic-verb)

Tags: biblatex

How can I customize `BibLaTeX`, so that I get the following?:

- N.N. (or O.V.) in my bibliography **when no author is given in my .bib-file**
- n.d. (or o.J.) in my bibliography **when no year is given in my .bib-file**

So when no author and/ or date are given, I would like "N.N. (or O.V.)" and "n.d. (or o.J.)" to show up in my bibliography and in my citations as OV/ OJ.

So when both author and date are missing, like in this example...

```
@book{book05,
title = {Planen, Steuern, Entwickeln: über den Beitrag öffentlicher Akteure zur Entwicklung von Stadt und Land},
publisher = {Edition Stadt-Entwicklung},
location = {Dortmund}
}
```

...the result in my bibliography should be like (of course depending on my defined bibliography style)...

> O.V.: *Planen, Steuern, Entwickeln: über den Beitrag öffentlicher Akteure zur Entwicklung von Stadt und Land.* Dortmund: Edition Stadt-Entwicklung, o.J.

and the result in my citation should be:

> [NNnd] or [OVOJ]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%Schriftart Arial - ACHTUNG: Compile with XeLaTeX (not PDFLaTeX)!
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale = 1.0]

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} %showframe

%Deutsche Umlaute, Englisch
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}

%Anführungszeichen
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

%Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[style       = alphabetic-verb,
            backend     = biber,
            maxbibnames     = 2,
            minbibnames     = 2,
            maxalphanames   = 1,
            minalphanames   = 1,
            useeditor       = false,
            giveninits      = true
            ]{biblatex}

%Name, V.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 

%Doppelpunkt nach letztem Verfasser
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace} 

%Änderungen von Strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
                andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}, %et al.
                urlseen = {Abruf\addcolon} %Anpassung in "Abruf:" bei URLs
                }

%Kapitälchen Nachame und Vorname von Autoren in Bibliography
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
               or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}} and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} )                    }}

%Komma bei mehreren Quellen
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

%Semikolon bei mehreren Autoren
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

%Formatierung von Regular Types
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\textit{#1\isdot}}

%Formatierung bei mehreren Autoren
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}



\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ruhr,
  author = {{Regionalverband Ruhr}},
  title = {Marketingstrategie 2017-2022 der Ruhr Tourismus GmbH},
  year = {2017},
  keywords = {nosc}
}
@book{book05,
title = {Planen, Steuern, Entwickeln: über den Beitrag öffentlicher Akteure zur Entwicklung von Stadt und Land},
publisher = {Edition Stadt-Entwicklung},
location = {Dortmund}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{citeall}

\begin{document}

\citeall
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to use incomplete bib entries in your bib file? Why not simply add `author={N.N.},` etc to your bib enties where needed?

Comment: I thought about that, too, but when I do this with the year-field (n.d.), there pops up a warning sign next to it. Is it better to just ignore it?

Comment: *in JabRef, which I am using to manage my literature

Comment: The thing with the date is pretty much straightforward, but the name is a bit more tricky due to the structure of the bibmacros involved. The idea is simple, but there are a quite a few macros to be redefined and one has to be careful to avoid interferences between the different macros.

Comment: @moewe I see, thanks! - I think I will just come to terms with the entries `author={N.N.}` and `year = {n.d.}` and close this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers of Mensch and moewe, I came to terms with just using `author={N.N.}` and `year = {n.d.}` in my bib entries, since it only evokes a warning in JabRef but apart from this, it gives me the right entries in my document (bibliography and citations).